# Sign the pdf using e-token in java

Tags: java, digital-signature

I am trying to sign digitally in pdf using java and iText .But have faced a problem .

```
ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Here the `BouncyCastleDigest()` is not found. And also get an error  MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS); here.
The error is :

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;`
```

Comment: `BouncyCastleDigest` is located in iText itself, in the package `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security`. If it cannot be found, you have an ancient or broken iText jar. The other error sounds like you don't have BouncyCastle installed, at least not the required version.

Comment: I have get the Exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject()Lorg/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive;" at MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);  What is the solution of this problem?\

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` - That clearly indicates that you have a wrong BouncyCastle jar on your classpath. Replace it by the correct one.